# How to make a menu like this one?

Tags: routes, navigation

This menu looks really nice. Im trying to do one similar. Any suggestions on how to start and what modules should I use.

[image: Discovery news drop down menu]

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about implementing a functionality, or a layout seen in a site, for which only a screenshot or a site URL is provided. Please see the [help] for more information about the types of question we answer here. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There is a module for that.  Its called [TB Mega Menu](https://www.drupal.org/project/tb_megamenu).  It allows you to add markup and stuff to a menu.  It's pretty robust, if this is not what you are looking for then you will need to look into a custom solution such as a module or using views.

Comment: There are also other mega menu modules available.

Answer (score 1):

First, you could use modules like [TBMegaMenu](https://www.drupal.org/project/tb_megamenu) as chadpeppers already suggested. It's really robust and stable. If you are willing to pay, you could also go for [MD-Megamenu](http://megadrupal.com/project/md-megamenu).

Second, you could go the manual way by adding theme menu functions in your theme's template.php file. Drupal core provide functions like theme_menu_tree and theme_menu_link.

There is also another unique approach using menu_views module. If your theme supports dropdown menu, then just install menu_views module. Then create a view containing the list of your items. Now, add a new menu item and set its menu-item-type to views. You will get a list of available views. Select your view, and save the menu item. Now move this menu item under another menu i.e. make it a child of another item. Save the menu.

Now, when you will click the parent item of that views-menu item, you will see the view in the dropdown. This view can be styles as you wish using the various display options available. Possibilities are immense if you are comfortable with views.